# Blackberry Push Notification-Push service sdk error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-push

I install the blackberry sdk push server and i get app id and the port and i used the tutorial SamplePushEnabledApp i registred it with those data

Application ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

PPG Base URL** http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com

Push Port: xxxxxxxx

For push initiator application i use the url https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8443/sample-push-initiator/ successfully create application using this, provide APPID, name and service level = Push-Essential. appID is same as provide by RIM.

I am trying to push msg from push menu item but it's give me error INVALID subscribers.

I had add subscribers name as APP_ID given by RIM, I had also tried device PIN No. as subscriber name but same error occurs.

plz help me to solve this issue.
Is there any solution for that?

Comment: check this sample http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/07/push-notification-in-blackberry.html#links

Answer (score 0):

There are three things required to sent a request from client side: APP id, push port and PPG base url

and three things required to send a response from server side :PPG base url, push username and push password

check whether you are using the exact credentials that are provided by Blackberry. If these dont match, it gives the above error

Comment: What is the username and password? is it provide by RIM?

Comment: the username and password are the "BlackBerry Push Service Evaluation Credentials" that you receive in the mail from BlackBerryPushServices
Also called as pushUsername and pushPassword

Answer (score 0):

Though this may be very late to answer your problem/issue faced while implementing push service in BB device, But as, very recently I successfully able to implement this and I know how difficult to do this if you are not a BB app developer.

Hope you have gone through the below url for installing BB push service sdk on your PC.

```
http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/push_service_sdk.html
http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/developing_push_enabled_app.html
```

So for this if you are able to install the push service sdk(bpss-1.2.0.29.exe) you will be having one BPSS directory and under this the below thing will get created.

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.26
logs
pushsdk-high-level
pushsdk-low-level
Uninstall_BPSS
Push_Service_SDK_for_Java_InstallLog.log
```

Now I have used the pushsdk-low-level to push.

you can access this web app(push initiator cum content provider) by

```
https://localhost:8443/pushsdk-low-level
```

But before start pushing from this low-level push initiator you need to properly install the sample pushDemo app on your device.
NOTE: You can't test push service using the simulator.

Then you need to register with the Port(XXXXX), AppId(XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) and BPS server URL: http://cpXXXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com, Push Initiator Application URL: http://XX.XXXX.XXX.XX:8443/pushsdk-low-level, and use pubic(BIS) network selected.

Now let me tell you what this sample pushDemo does.
first it will try to use the Push initiator application URL to subcribe/store the BB device PIN to have the information about all PINs that have been register with your Push initiator(here our push-low-level app). But for testing this you can ignore by commenting the below code line in RegisterCommand.java class of the sample PushDemo app

```
ContentProviderProtocol.performCommand( ContentProviderProtocol.CMD_SUBSCRIBE, username, password, isEnterprise, tx );
```

Now run this modified app on you device and insert all data required for registration, you will be asked to input username/password, give anything. and register it should register successfully.

Once you have successfully registered your app on your BB device.

Now you should be able to push from your push-low-level web app to your pushDemo client app on your device. NOTE: the address that is been asked on push-low-level push page is nothing but the PIN of your device.

Ping me if you any other help on implementing this.

Comment: Hi
I had successfully implemented the BB push notification and had given an expiry date in August .Still suddenly the server started giving a 401 error and push notifications have been stopped being generated.Can you help me with this ?